# How to specify tab delimitation file load in Oracle sqlldr control file?

Tags: oracle, file, text, sql-loader

This should be simple, but what is the correct syntax for an Oracle sqlldr control file in order to specify tab delimited/separated data?

---

FWIW, I found the file was UTF16 and not UTF8, and was editing fine but would introduce null bytes as Oracle read the control file.  Can't even replicate today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [this thread](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=15821), it should be `fields terminated by '\t'` (don't have an Oracle installation at hand to verify that this is correct).

Comment: +1 See documentation at: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10701/ldr_concepts.htm#sthref374

Comment: Tx Shannon, +1, that reference does indeed give some certainty!-)

Comment: I'm wondering if the control file has control characters in there.  It is on a Unix box, but \t is not resolving. 11g here. Will report back.